# AWS Amplify package supports both Vue2 and Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

In my current project I am using Vue 2 (2.6.12) and

Amplify versions:

```
"@aws-amplify/api-graphql": "^2.2.18",
"@aws-amplify/ui-vue": "^0.2.20",
"aws-amplify": "^3.3.1"
```

I want to upgrade my project to Vue3. I want to know will this mentioned version of amplify will work on Vue 3 or I have to upgrade amplify version too.

What will be breaking changes if I upgrade amplify version?

I have checked from documentation on aws-amplify then I find out the statement that now amplify support vue3 so I am curious is this same version I am using will work fine on Vue 3

Comment: It's easier to check the implementation yourself in such cases. Here you can see it relies on `Vue`. There's none in Vue 3. https://unpkg.com/browse/@aws-amplify/ui-vue@0.2.20/dist/index.js